# No module named pycomm.ab_comm.slc

Tags: python, asp.net

I am working on asp.net application where i have to overwrite the contents of a variable named "ip" from a python file. Here i wrote the code to display the contents of variable named "ip" from a python file.

```
ScriptEngine engine = Python.CreateEngine();
ScriptScope scope = engine.CreateScope();
string s = Server.MapPath("~/Emailsms.PY");
engine.ExecuteFile(s, scope);
var result = scope.GetVariable("ip");
```

But when the control reaches at ExecuteFile then a error comes

```
"No module named pycomm.ab_comm.slc"
```

How to resolve this error?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem should be solved by a simple `pip install pycomm`

Edit : in a command line

Comment: Kindly describe your answer

Comment: Simply run `pip install pycomm` in a terminal (or cmd on windows). You need to have pip on your path. If it's not, and you have python on your path, you can run `python -m pip install pycomm`